# finding size of object inside jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

js code:

```
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            if(key == 'REGEXP' || there is only one object in data){
                $changableValidationType.append('<option selected="selected" value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');                    
            }
            else
                $changableValidationType.append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
    });
```

If there is only one object in data or its REGEXP then I want to make it selected="selected",

Comment: Please share how does your `data` look like? How do you make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to check length of objects inside `data`

```
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            if(key == 'REGEXP' || (typeof(value)== object && value.length == 1)){
                $changableValidationType.append('<option selected="selected" value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');                    
            }
            else
                $changableValidationType.append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(key == 'REGEXP' || (typeof data =="object" && data.length == 1) || typeof data == "undefined"){
```

you can take of the last check if data needs to be defined, im not really sure how you would get in there if data wasnt defined though.

Comment: data.length is undefined

Comment: what is in your data then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use something like this. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcPQf/)

```
var size = assocArrayLength(data);
if (data['REGEXP'] || size === 1) {
    var key = Object.keys(data)[0];
    var value = data[key];

    console.log(key + ":" + value);
    $changableValidationType.append('<option selected="selected" value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
} else {
    console.log(size);

    for(var key in data){
        $changableValidationType.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + data[key] + '</option>');
    }
}

function assocArrayLength(arr){
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in arr) {
        if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
```

Because associative arrays does not behave like *normal* arrays in JavaScript. For more information you can read a more detailed answer about size in these *arrays* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-javascript-object-ie-associative-array)